# What exactly is the "real interpolation space" $(L^q, W^{2,q})_{1-p^{-1},p}$ for $1<p,q<\infty$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces, interpolation-theory

I came across the notation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space#Real_interpolation
the real interpolation space is discussed for Bessel potential spaces.

However, I do not see exactly how to apply this general theory to the specific case
\begin{equation}
 (L^q(\Omega), W^{2,q}(\Omega))_{1-\frac{1}{p},p} 
\end{equation}
for $1<p,q<\infty$ and a bounded region $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundaries.

Could anyone pleaes clarify for this case? In particular, do I have to use Bessel potential spaces or Sobolev–Slobodeckij spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifying interpolation spaces is in general a non-trivial task. In your case you get certain [Besov spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Besov_space); it is shown in Theorem 17.24 of

*Leoni, Giovanni*, [**A first course in Sobolev spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1090/gsm/181), Graduate Studies in Mathematics 181. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 978-1-4704-2921-8/hbk; 978-1-4704-4226-2/ebook). xxii, 734 p. (2017). [ZBL1382.46001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1382.46001).

that we have the identification
$$ (L^q(\mathbb R^n), W^{k,q}(\mathbb R^n))_{\sigma,p} = B^{\sigma k,q}_p(\mathbb R^n). $$
So in your case, we would expect $B^{2(1-\frac1p),q}_p(\Omega)$, which is indeed what you get.
Besov spaces on bounded (and regular) domains can be defined in several equivalent ways, such as the restriction of functions on $B^{s,p}_q(\mathbb R^n)$ to $\Omega$. See for instance the discussion at the end of Section 17.3 of the aformentioned text.

Other characterisations, and a more comprehensive treatment of these spaces can be found in Chapter I.3 of

*Triebel, Hans*, Theory of function spaces, Monographs in Mathematics, Vol. 78. Basel-Boston-Stuttgart: Birkhäuser Verlag, DM 90.00 (1983). [ZBL0546.46027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0546.46027).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been looking into Besov spaces as well. Is it true in general that $W^{k,q}$ is continuously embedded in the Besov space you wrote above?

Comment: @Keith Yes, this is a general property of interpolation spaces $X_{\theta} = [X_0,X_1]_{\sigma,q}$ whenever $X_0 \hookrightarrow X_1$.